# As an administrator how to restrict users from Installing certain packages?

Tags: apt, package-management, administration

I want to know how does an administrator disable users/groups from downloading certain packages. For example, let it be the `youtube-dl` package which enables download YouTube videos, or let it be `rtorrent`.

So what should be done to disable the user(s) from installing certain packages. Consider like that the packages type is related to mp3/videos/torrent/etc...

**PS:** Those users have `sudo` permissions

Comment: Do these users have `sudo` permission?

Comment: Yes, definitely. Since, I have mentioned it like they can download packages, but a few of the packages related to videos/mp3/torrent has to be disabled for them.

Comment: Only administrators can install ANY packages.

Comment: Could you explain a bit on the context? You will not be able to act as a "super" - administrator among other administrators, but you can cheat to make it more difficult. It depends on the situation, the level of your fellow-administrators if that is an acceptable solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First you should know as the others are sudoers then you can't restrict their access, but there is a tricky simple way to do what you want.

First of all you should specify all packages that you would to restrict.

Open the sudoer config file:

```
sudo visudo
```

for example I'm gonna here prevent the user named `user` from installing youtube-dl. Add this line to the file.

```
user ALL = ! /usr/bin/apt-get install youtube-dl
```

Now the user named `user` couldn't install the package `youtube-dl`.

```
$ sudo apt-get install youtube-dl
[sudo] password for user: 
Sorry, user user is not allowed to execute '/usr/bin/apt-get install youtube-dl' as root on userPC.
```

Redo the same operation for other users and other packages.

At the end you should also prevent those users from editing the sudoer config file itself so as above you have to add the line for each user

```
user ALL = ! /usr/bin/apt-get install youtube-dl \
           ! /usr/sbin/visudo
```

So now for user

```
$ sudo visudo 
[sudo] password for user: 
Sorry, user user is not allowed to execute '/usr/sbin/visudo' as root on userPC.
```

Comment: You are welcome, But be in mind if your users are advanced users, its better to remove them from `sudo`. The above can be override easily by some advanced user

Comment: what do mean by advanced users here? and how could they override it?

Comment: a user with `sudo` can easily change the root password and thus he can use the `root`  , and in this case no meaning for whatever you do

Comment: Is there any way to restrict the sudo users from executing commands like sudo reboot/shutdown..?

Comment: Yes there is, just read my answer above, I stated how to do that